# Turtle screen gets closed when .onclick() or onscreenclick() is used

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a global variable, 'is_game_on' set to 'False' to start with. I have a turtle which responds to `.ondrag()` function. My program works perfectly fine if I change the 'is_game_on' variable to 'True' (The main program runs in a while loop when 'is_game_on' is 'True').

In the same Screen I have created turtle (a text- 'Click to start') in the top right of the screen, which I want to return 'is_game_on' = 'True' when the mouse is clicked on it so that the rest of my program starts working there after. However, my screen gets closed when I click the mouse. I think this is because of the command `screen.exitonclick()` at the end. Appreciate any suggestions how to avoid this problem.

Below is my code. I want to start with 'is_game_on == False' and with the output a static display. Then when I click the mouse on 'Click to Start', a mechanism to trigger  'is_game_on" as True and then the ball starts bouncing up and down.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time


# is_game_on = False
is_game_on = True

def click(i, j):
    global is_game_on
    if i >= 250 and j >= 300:
        is_game_on = True
        print(is_game_on)
    return is_game_on

class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.color('black')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        self.penup()
        self.speed(6)
        self.goto(0, -355)
        self.x_move = 0
        self.y_move = 1
        self.move_speed = 10

    def move(self):
        xcor_new = self.xcor() + self.x_move
        ycor_new = self.ycor() + self.y_move
        self.goto(xcor_new, ycor_new)

    def bounce_y(self):
        self.y_move *= -1

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('square')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, -380)
        self.color('blue')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=.5, stretch_len=10)

    def move(self,i, j):
        self.goto(i,  -380)

class Start(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(250, 300)
        self.color('blue')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=10)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.write('Click to Start', font=('Arial', 35, 'bold'))

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
screen.bgcolor('white')
screen.setup(1200, 800)

screen.tracer(0)

paddle = Paddle()
ball = Ball()

screen.listen()
paddle.ondrag(paddle.move)
screen.onclick(click)

start = Start()


while is_game_on:
    time.sleep(0)
    screen.update()
    ball.move()
    if ball.ycor() >= 375:
        ball.bounce_y()
    if (abs(ball.xcor() - paddle.xcor()) < 120) and ball.ycor() == -355:
        ball.bounce_y()

screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and errors and lot of web searches, I found the solution.

The screen closing problem can be simply avoided by importing turtle and adding `turtle.done()` command just before `screen.exitonclick()` command. The complete code will be.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time
import turtle


is_game_on = False
# is_game_on = True

def click(i, j):
    global is_game_on
    if i >= 250 and j >= 300:
        is_game_on = True
        print(is_game_on)
    return is_game_on

class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.color('black')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        self.penup()
        self.speed(6)
        self.goto(0, -355)
        self.x_move = 0
        self.y_move = 1
        self.move_speed = 10

    def move(self):
        xcor_new = self.xcor() + self.x_move
        ycor_new = self.ycor() + self.y_move
        self.goto(xcor_new, ycor_new)

    def bounce_y(self):
        self.y_move *= -1

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('square')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, -380)
        self.color('blue')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=.5, stretch_len=10)

    def move(self,i, j):
        self.goto(i,  -380)

class Start(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(250, 300)
        self.color('blue')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=10)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.write('Click to Start', font=('Arial', 35, 'bold'))

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
screen.bgcolor('white')
screen.setup(1200, 800)

screen.tracer(0)

paddle = Paddle()
ball = Ball()

screen.listen()
paddle.ondrag(paddle.move)
screen.onclick(click)

start = Start()


while is_game_on:
    time.sleep(0)
    screen.update()
    ball.move()
    if ball.ycor() >= 375:
        ball.bounce_y()
    if (abs(ball.xcor() - paddle.xcor()) < 120) and ball.ycor() == -355:
        ball.bounce_y()

screen.update()
turtle.done()
screen.exitonclick()
```

**The animation can work by moving the while loop into the `click()` function. The code will be as follows.**

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time
import turtle


is_game_on = False
# is_game_on = True

def click(i, j):
    global is_game_on
    if i >= 250 and j >= 300:
        is_game_on = True
        print(is_game_on)
        while is_game_on:
            time.sleep(0)
            screen.update()
            ball.move()
            if ball.ycor() >= 375:
                ball.bounce_y()
            if (abs(ball.xcor() - paddle.xcor()) < 120) and ball.ycor() == -355:
                ball.bounce_y()
    return is_game_on

class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.color('black')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        self.penup()
        self.speed(6)
        self.goto(0, -355)
        self.x_move = 0
        self.y_move = 1
        self.move_speed = 10

    def move(self):
        xcor_new = self.xcor() + self.x_move
        ycor_new = self.ycor() + self.y_move
        self.goto(xcor_new, ycor_new)

    def bounce_y(self):
        self.y_move *= -1

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('square')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, -380)
        self.color('blue')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=.5, stretch_len=10)

    def move(self,i, j):
        self.goto(i,  -380)

class Start(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(250, 300)
        self.color('blue')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=4, stretch_len=10)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.write('Click to Start', font=('Arial', 35, 'bold'))

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
screen.bgcolor('white')
screen.setup(1200, 800)

screen.tracer(0)

paddle = Paddle()
ball = Ball()

screen.listen()
paddle.ondrag(paddle.move)
screen.onclick(click)

start = Start()


screen.update()
turtle.done()
screen.exitonclick()
```